# What is the correct way to handle nullptr const char* when using const std::string& as method argument type?

Tags: c++, string, null, nullptr

I have a method which takes `const std::string&` argument. It will be typically used like that: `a.doSomething("some string")` but I want to check whether string supplied was not implicitly constructed from a `nullptr`.

An example:

```
#include <string>

struct A {
    void doSomething(const std::string& arg) {
        // if (arg == nullptr) throw; // This is what I want (doesn't work)
        if(arg.empty()) // This does not detect nullptr
            throw;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const char* null_str;
    std::string s("");
    A a;
    a.doSomething(null_str);
    a.doSomething(s);

    return 0;
}
```

What is the correct, elegant way to do this? Should I provide an overload `doSomething(const char* arg)` which would check `arg` before explicitly constructing `std::string` from it at passing it to the other overload?

Comment: Note that `""` is not a `nullptr` and neither is `null_str`, because it's an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: The correct way to handle this is with a visit to the cubicle of the responsible developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I want to check whether string supplied was not implicitly constructed from a `nullptr`

Constructing a string from a null pointer has undefined behaviour. You need to detect this *before* attempting to construct such a string. That means you cannot check it inside the function being called: it's the caller that constructs the string.

> Should I provide an overload `doSomething(const char* arg)` which would check arg

That seems like a perfectly good approach to me.

Depending on what specifically you want, you could also check to see if your implementation has a debug mode where the construction of *any* string from `nullptr` gets detected and aborts your program.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (arg == nullptr) throw;
```

doesn't work because arg can never be null.  You pass a reference to arg and a reference can never be null.  So there is no need to check for null.  You can simply remove the null check because it is inappropriate.

See:

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#refs-not-null

If you want to check for a null char* pointer, then yes you need a function taking a char*:

```
 void doSomething(const char* arg)
```

You can either change void to return a result code or raise an exception or indeed some other thing.

Comment: Another thing: `throw;` is for rethrowing an exception, not for throwing a new exception. It should be e.g. `throw InvalidArgumentException();`.

Comment: I know about both of these things, just wanted to make the example short.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an overload like

```
void doSomething(std::nullptr_t);
```

Comment: To be clear, given `const char *s;`, `doSomething(s)` would never pick that overload, regardless of whether `s` is a null pointer.